# "request.setAttribute(message,"中文")" results in mistaken code in JSP Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, error-code

UserServlet.java

[image: UserServlet.java]

I used `request.setAttribute()` in servlet to save the prompted meassage and then showed them in jsp page. But i found that if i set the message to Chinese ,it turned out to be  mistaken code. And the `request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8")` was no use. What should i do?

login.jsp

[image: login.jsp]
[image: show]

Comment: whar error do you get?

Comment: No error!But it appears error-code to show the message.

Comment: `request.setCharacterEncoding` has no effect on `request.getAttribute` (as what you've stored there previously stays there as a String, it is not interpreted again). `request.setCharacterEncoding` only affects subsequent `request.getParameter` calls and reading the body using `getReader` (see the Javadoc)

Comment: Is the output the UTF-8 encoding of your input? We can't tell due to the missing code points (the diamonds)

Comment: yes,I have found that .But is there no methods to solve the code problem?

Comment: I have uploaded the question.

Comment: @Jim: replacement characters represent missing font glyphs, not "missing code points", that doesn't make sense.

Comment: it's Chinese characters not missing font glyphs

Comment: @BalusC You are of course right. I was thinking "missing glyphs for code points" and left out the important bit.

Comment: @Jim er.i can't understand you ..should I show you the whole code of the two(servlet and jsp )?